# Use tr with arrays

Tags: perl, tr

I am trying to use the tr function specifying two arrays, as the to and from sets. the translation doesn't seem to be working, or i am not understanding it correctly.
I am new to perl, so please let me know if i am doing something wrong

## I load the arrays as (I know this part works):

```
open my $fh,'<',"${main_dir}/char_convert" or die "Cannot open allowed conversion file";
my @from_set;
my @to_set;
my @conversion;
while (my $lines = <$fh>) {
  @conversion = split(" ",$lines);
  push @from_set,$conversion[0];
  push @to_set,$conversion[1];
}

#The variable $line holds the data I want converted:
my $statement;
my $result;
$statement = "tr\@from_set\@to_set\$line;"; # Setup the tr command
$result = eval($statement); # perform the conversion
print "$line\n";
```

the result is the same as the data going in. No conversion appears to have taken place.
What am I doing wrong?

An example part of the data is "PICAÑA".
The line in the conversion file is "Ñ N"
So I expect to get out "PICANA", but I get the original data

Thanks for looking

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56543259/edit) to include more information if anyone asks.  For example, including a sample of your `char_convert` file would make the question more complete.  However, as you already have an answer, it's probably not necessary in this situation :) .

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you went with `tr///` because it's faster than `s///`. If so, using `eval` each time you do a translation defies the purpose. The only way it's going to be faster if is you use `eval` once, but perform multiple transliterations.

In addition to making it possible to use the compiled `tr///` multiple times, the following fixes the Perl syntax errors as well as the [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) bugs:

```
my $from_set = join '', @from_set;
my $to_set   = join '', @to_set;

my $tr = eval("sub { \$_[0] =~ tr/\Q$from_set\E/\Q$to_set\E/r }")
   or die($@);

my $output = $tr->($input);
```

If, on the other hand, you're only performing the transliteration once, then you're making your life more complicated and slowing down your program for nothing by using `tr///`. Use `s///` instead.

```
my %map; @map{@from_set} = @to_set;
my $from_set = join '', @from_set;
my $re = qr/([\Q$from_set\E])/;

my $output = $input =~ s/$re/$map{$1}/gr;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Helped a lot. As i said i am new to perl, so i will make "stupid" mistakes. But that is how we learn.

Comment: There was a bug I've just fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$statement` is a bit off, as the normal form would be `$line =~ tr/a/b/`, right? So should be like this:

```
my $statement = "\$line =~ tr/\Q@from_set\E/\Q@to_set\E/;"
```

The `$line` should remain a variable during evaluation, so it is escaped as `\$line`.  The contents of the `@from_set` and `@to_set` should be interpolated into `$statement`, so they are given without `\`.

Comment: vlumi, I think you may also need `local $"=''` before evaluating `$statement`, depending on the Perl version.  On my test system, `my @a=1,2,3; "@a"` evaluates to `"1 2 3"` rather than to `"123"`, because the default `$"` is `" "`.  See [perldoc](https://perldoc.pl/variables/$%22).

Comment: @cxw As long as the spaces are in the same place on both sides, it doesn't actually matter, although it would be more fail-safe. Maybe even properly join them into scalar values and put those into the evaluated statement...

Comment: @ikegami Fixed, I hope..?

Comment: Never seen it used it with arrays before, but no reason it shouldn't. I tested it to be sure (`perl -E'@a=qw(| |); say "\Q@a"'`)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here. They are mainly around the syntax of your `tr/../../` statement. It should be like this:

```
$line =~ tr/CHARS/CHARS/;
```

You have the `$line` in the wrong place and you're using backslashes instead of forward slashes (you can use forward slashes as the delimiter in a `tr/.../.../` statement, but remember that they have a special meaning in double-quoted strings).

This seems to do what you want (I've switched to using the internal `DATA` filehandle for ease of testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use utf8;

my @from;
my @to;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @conv = split;
  push @from, $conv[0];
  push @to,   $conv[1];
}

my $line = 'PICAÑA';

my $statement = "\$line =~ tr/@from/@to/";

eval $statement;

say $line;

__DATA__
Ñ N
Ê E
```

I don't, obviously, know exactly which characters you're dealing with here but it looks like you might find [Text::Unidecode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Unidecode) useful.

**Update:** it's also worth pointing out that the `tr/.../.../` statement still isn't quite right (although it works). If you print `$statement`, you'll see it gives:

```
$line =~ tr/Ñ Ê/N E/
```

That extra space comes from the fact that Perl puts a space between array elements when there are interpolated in a double-quoted string. If you cared, you could fix that by setting `$"` to an empty string.

**Update 2:**

Having thought about it a little more, I think I wouldn't use arrays at all. Why not use scalars instead?

```
my $from = '';
my $to   = '';

# And then, in the loop...

$from .= $conv[0];
$to   .= $conv[1];

# And later still...

my $statement = "\$line =~ tr/$from/$to/";
```

Comment: Injection bug! Use`"tr/\Q$from\E/\Q$to\E/"`

Comment: You can use the join function to concatenate a list, i.e. my $from = join('', @from_set);

Comment: @ikegami: `\Q` has no effect in transliterations.

Comment: 1) That's no excuse for leaving a bug in your code, and 2) I didn't suggest you use it in a transliteration literal; I suggested you use it in a double-quoted string literal.

Answer (score 2):

From Perl Mongers if you want safety against injection of slashes you should use quotemeta like this or use the @ikegami solution:

```
eval sprintf "tr/%s/%s/", map quotemeta, $oldlist, $newlist;
```

https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=445971